# Inviting Users to Facebook Events using JavaScript and Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Within my application I want to invite users to events by using the Graph API.
I've created a test account which is admin for the page used for creating events.

I was able to successfully invite users both from the admin and the page account using the Graph API Explorer:

HTTP POST to "page-id"/invited?users="user1,user2,..."

My javascript looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+event+'/invited?users='+usersstring+'?access_token='+token,
type: 'POST',
success: function(result) 
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
});
```

> usersstring looks just as this "user1,user2,user3"

When I run it I get an error back:

```
   "error": {
  "message": "(#114) An id must be a valid ID string (e.g., \"123\")",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 114
```

}

I don't really understand what this means since within the API the Server always returns OK and the invitation is correctly send to the user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your URL:

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+event+'/invited?users='+usersstring+'?access_token='+token,
```

It should not have a question mark for the access token, it should be an ampersand, such as:

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+event+'/invited?users='+usersstring+'&access_token='+token,
```

However from my own experience, inviting users to events through the graph API is impossible. The graph explorer gives me a "true" return value as well, but whenever I use the same technique in my app or even use Postman on Chrome to post the URL directly, it tells me that it's deprecated in v2.0 and above, even if I specify v1.0 in the URL. I don't know how to get it to work totally, unfortunately.